# What is the proper way to inflate a ListView footer in Android?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

Can anyone shed some light on the proper way to inflate a ListView footer in Android?

Based on my understanding, the correct way to use inflate is to pass it at least two parameters, the resource to inflate and the root ViewGroup. Optionally, one can pass in the third bool parameter indicating whether or not the resource should be attached to the ViewGroup.

Now, if I try to inflate a footer this way, it does not work (the footer does not appear in the UI).

```java
TextView footerView = (TextView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.footer_view, getListView(), false); 
getListView().addFooterView(footerView);
```

Essentially, the only way that it works is by passing null as the ViewGroup.

```java
TextView footerView = (TextView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.footer_view, null, false);
getListView().addFooterView(footerView);
```

However, based on everything that I have read, this is considered bad practice. Thus, the question: **What is the proper way to inflate a ListView footer?**

Thank you.

Footer View XML:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/footerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="@string/add_new_todo_item_string"
    android:textSize="24sp" >

</TextView>
```

**I am not sure why, but both versions are now working in the emulator ...**  Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: I haven't tried inflating a layout to be a footer. The fact that the footer is managed by a framework-supplied `ListAdapter` may be part of the problem, though I wouldn't have expected that to be the case. When you use your first bit of code, and you examine the results in Hierarchy View or **`uiautomatorviewer`**, do you get any clues? Also, you might consider pasting in the contents of your `footer_view` layout file, in case that gives us some ideas.

Comment: @CommonsWare I haven't looked at the Hierarchy View, but I will check it out shortly and update the post.

Answer (score -2):

There is no kind of any bad practice. This is correct answer:

```
TextView footerView = (TextView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.footer_view, null, false);
getListView().addFooterView(footerView);
```

Comment: Well, actually, it can cause problems with `RelativeLayout` if you don't pass the parent container into `inflate()`. That's why the general guidance is to use the three-parameter version of `inflate()`.

Comment: @CommonsWare Exactly :)